# Remove "product-category" from WooCommerce but only on first level

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

Is there a way to remove "product-category" bit from the breadcrumb in WooCommerce but the catch is to do it only on the first level. So for example:

Home > Category > Sub-Category

The "product-category" bit only needs to be removed from "Category" part but not "Sub-Category" part in the above breadcrumb.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter to remove the first level product category

```
// change the breadcrumb on the product page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'custom_breadcrumb', 20, 2 );
function custom_breadcrumb( $crumbs, $breadcrumb ) {

    // only on the single product page
    // if ( ! is_product() ) {
    //     return $crumbs;
    // }

    //get product details
    //global $product;

    //for print array
    // print_r($crumbs);
    //die;
    

    // remove the first element of the array "$crumbs"
    unset($crumbs[1]);
    return $crumbs;
}
```